# Поиск в mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Как в mongodb искать по первым символам? 
Например так:

- т* - все слова,что начинаются с "т";
- те* - все слова,что начинаются с "те".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения. Я конечно не гуру регулярных выражений, но должно работать:

```
var users = db.collection("users");
users.find( { 
    name: { 
        $regex: /^буквы/i 
    }
})
```

Где "буквы" - то, что должно быть в начале строки.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать $regex (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

а можно и так:

```
db.table.insert({name: 'mysql'})
db.table.insert({name: 'mongo'})
db.table.insert({name: 'oracle'})

db.table.find({name: /o/})  //like '%o%' -> mongo, oracle

db.table.find({name: /^my/}) //like 'my%' -> mysql

db.table.find({name: /go$/}) //like '%go' -> mongo
```

Comment: Тогда как засунуть в регулярное выражение строку?